# Why 'for loop' of pytorch is 10 times faster than tensorflow2.3?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, for-loop, pytorch

I achieve a part in two ways: pytorch and tensorflow2.3, but in 'for loop', pytorch is 10 times faster than tensorflow2.3, and I don't know why ? Could you please help me about that?

**'for loop part' in TF2.3:**

```
 for i in range(seq_len):

        m_t = mels[:, i, :]

        a1_t, a2_t, a3_t, a4_t = (a[:, i, :] for a in aux_split)

        x = tf.concat([x, m_t, a1_t], axis=1)
        x = self.I(x)

        _, h1 = rnn1(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1))

        x = x + h1
        inp = tf.concat([x, a2_t], axis=1)
        _, h2 = rnn2(tf.expand_dims(inp, axis=1))

        x = x + h2
        x = tf.concat([x, a3_t], axis=1)
        x = tf.nn.relu(self.fc1(x))

        x = tf.concat([x, a4_t], axis=1)
        x = tf.nn.relu(self.fc2(x))

        logits = self.fc3(x)

        if self.mode == 'RAW' :
            posterior = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=1)
            distrib = tfp.distributions.Categorical(posterior, dtype=tf.float32)
            
            sample = 2 * distrib.sample() / (self.n_classes - 1.) - 1.
            output.append(sample)
            x = tf.expand_dims(sample, axis=-1)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Unknown model mode value - ", self.mode)

        if i % 100 == 0:
            gen_rate = (i + 1) / (time.time() - start) * b_size_np / 1000
            progress_callback(i, seq_len, b_size, gen_rate)
```

**Cost about 50s finished for loop.**

**for loop part' in Pytorch:**

```
  for i in range(seq_len):

            m_t = mels[:, i, :]

            a1_t, a2_t, a3_t, a4_t = (a[:, i, :] for a in aux_split)

            x = torch.cat([x, m_t, a1_t], dim=1)
            x = self.I(x)
            h1 = rnn1(x, h1)

            x = x + h1
            inp = torch.cat([x, a2_t], dim=1)

            h2 = rnn2(inp, h2)

            x = x + h2
            x = torch.cat([x, a3_t], dim=1)
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))

            x = torch.cat([x, a4_t], dim=1)
            x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))

            logits = self.fc3(x)

            if self.mode == 'RAW' :
                posterior = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)
                distrib = torch.distributions.Categorical(posterior)

                sample = 2 * distrib.sample().float() / (self.n_classes - 1.) - 1.
                output.append(sample)
                x = sample.unsqueeze(-1)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Unknown model mode value - ", self.mode)
```

**Cost just 5s finished for loop!**

I really need your help and know how to change the tf2.3 code, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you should use `axis=1` in TF? That's channel right? Then I think it should be `axis=-1` instead.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Can you tell me why? I get the same output shape when I use axis=1 and axis= -1. What't the different?

Comment: It's about the channel axis of the tensor that both libs use differently. For example a 1280x720 image tensor in Tensorflow will have shape `(1, 720,1280,3)` while the one in Pytorch will have `(1, 3, 720, 1280)`

Comment: The reason the output shape you see being the same is because it's rank 2 tensor. Like `(1, 1024)`. But RNN layers need rank 3. So if the `axis=1` in `tf.concat` is already correct then maybe `tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)` should be `axis=-1` instead.

Comment: Now that I think about it. There isn't a single `unsqueeze` in the pytorch code. Which means the TF code isn't a perfect replica.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Thanks for your reply. I check it again and I find that in pytorch rnn1 , it exactly just use the GRUcell from the trained GRU layer( just inherit the bias and weight), so here GRUcell input is just rank 2.for pytorch But I can't get  find the relica of that in tensorflow, so  for the same rank 2 input, I use GRU and expand 2d input to 3d input to feed. But result is wrong.....Can you tell me in TF2.3 how to get a GRUcell from trained tf.layers.GRU layers like Pytorch? I will show the pytorch's rnn1 code as follows:

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen  In Pytorch: rnn1 and rnn2 is  from such fuc where gru  para here is a trained GRU layers . And I don't know how to write it in Tensorflow......
    def get_gru_cell(self, gru):
        gru_cell = nn.GRUCell(gru.input_size, gru.hidden_size)
        gru_cell.weight_hh.data = gru.weight_hh_l0.data
        gru_cell.weight_ih.data = gru.weight_ih_l0.data
        gru_cell.bias_hh.data = gru.bias_hh_l0.data
        gru_cell.bias_ih.data = gru.bias_ih_l0.data
        return gru_cell